# Timestamp to date convert issue in Snowflake

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have one Snowflake table which contains `TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9)` column named as `COLUMN_B_TS`, it value is always like `"2012-04-25 00:00:00.000"`, we want to run statement like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "WH_A"."SCHEMA_A"."NEW_TABLE" 
SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS), COLUMN_C 
FROM "WH_A"."SCHEMA_A"."EXISTING_TABLE"
```

but it returns error:

> "SQL compilation error: Missing column specification"

I think there is no syntax error of above statement, so what is the
problem here? Or Is there some restriction of the timestamp to date
convert in Snowflake?

If I want to achieve above goal, how can I do? Thanks, keen to know the answer, block here now. Thanks!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the [Create Table As Select (CTAS)](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-table.html#create-table-as-select-also-referred-to-as-ctas) pattern, and thus need to include the AS, but given the error message:

> Missing column specification

that implies you have that in your real code, but the second column needs a valid name.

```
create table EXISTING_TABLE (column_a int, column_b timestamp, column_c text);

insert into EXISTING_TABLE values
    (1, '2022-08-28 16:54:01'::timestamp, 'row 1'),
    (2, '2022-08-28 16:54:02'::timestamp, 'row 2');
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE NEW_TABLE AS
    SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B) as column_b, COLUMN_C 
    FROM EXISTING_TABLE;
```

```
select * from NEW_TABLE;
```

| COLUMN_A | COLUMN_B | COLUMN_C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-28 | row 1 |
| 2 | 2022-08-28 | row 2 |

Answer (score 0):

> I think there is no syntax error of above statement, so what is the problem here?

The SELECT statement is fine as long as it is run standalone.

```
CREATE DATABASE WH_A;
CREATE SCHEMA SCHEMA_A;
CREATE TABLE EXISTSING_TABLE(COLUMN_A TEXT, COLUMN_B_TS TIMESTAMP_NTZ(9), 
                             COLUMN_C INT);
INSERT INTO EXISTSING_TABLE VALUES ('A', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), 1);

SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS), COLUMN_C 
FROM WH_A.SCHEMA_A.EXISTSING_TABLE;
```

Output:

[image]

The second column has a name that is a column expression `TO_DATE(...)` and it has not a true alias/name.

The `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` behaves very similar to [CREATE VIEW AS SELECT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-view.html#optional-parameters) on that matter:

> If any of the columns in the view are based on expressions (not just simple column names), then you must supply a column name for each column in the view.

It is not possible to:

```
CREATE VIEW WH_A.SCHEMA_A.NEW_VIEW
AS
SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS), COLUMN_C 
FROM WH_A.SCHEMA_A.EXISTSING_TABLE;
-- Missing column specification
```

---

There are two options to solve the missing specification:

a) provide an alias at query level

```
CREATE VIEW WH_A.SCHEMA_A.NEW_TABLE
AS
SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS) AS COLUMN_B_TS, COLUMN_C 
FROM WH_A.SCHEMA_A.EXISTSING_TABLE;
```

b) provide explicit column specification(query stays the same)

```
CREATE TABLE WH_A.SCHEMA_A.NEW_TABLE(COLUMN_A TEXT, COLUMN_B_TS DATE, COLUMN_C INT)
AS
SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS), COLUMN_C 
FROM WH_A.SCHEMA_A.EXISTSING_TABLE;
```

Answer (score 0):

When we create a table using select statement (CTAS),
we have to give name to every columns.
In your case Snowflake does not know how to name the column containing to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS). Giving it a name will resolve the problem.

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE "WH_A"."SCHEMA_A"."NEW_TABLE"
SELECT COLUMN_A, to_DATE(COLUMN_B_TS) AS COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C
FROM "WH_A"."SCHEMA_A"."EXISTING_TABLE"